# Set a field 'unique' ONLY within a user (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a standard mongoose User Scheme, and a 'Uniform' scheme that holds dress items in the following way:

```
mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    items: { type: [String], unique: true }
})
```

Thing is, I want the items in the 'items' array to be unique only in the scope of the user. Meaning that I don't want a user to have serval uniforms with the same item. But I don't have any problem with other users having the same items as my user.

The current scheme prevents ANY uniform to have the same values inside 'items', I want it to be just within the scope of the user.
Can that even be done?

(In ruby on rails, the line that creates this behavior is: `validates_uniqueness_of :items, scope: [:user]`)

Answer (score 2):

If `User` and `Uniform` are different schemas (different collections) then having uniqueness achieved between keys of different collections cannot be done in mongodb.

We can have uniqueness achieved by combining different keys of a same collection using [Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/)

Comment: So setting an index: { "items": 1, "user": 1 }, will do the trick? how do I set this index as unique as well? and will I control the error message if a an instance wouldn't be saved because of this?